# How to make a series summation add up to its upper bound raised to a power?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an $f(j)$ (or perhaps many $f(j)$) that satisfies

$$\sum_{j=1}^{M} f(j)=M^a$$

($M\neq1,a\neq 0$. Mostly interested in $a=2$ case, with $M$ in the $10^5$ range.)

Please offer examples.

(Edit: $M$ is a positive integer, $a$ is real)

Comment: Is M a positive number or any real number??

Comment: Hint: What will be $f(j)$ if it satisfy the condition for every $M$...